# Is there any risk for oranges to lose vitamin C

Tags: fruit, vitamins

My understanding is that vitamin C easily undergoes oxidation. But for that to happen, the vitamin C has to be in contact with oxygen, e.g. with air. Therefore an orange doesn't start losing its vitamin C content by just because it's picked from a tree. It keeps that vitamin up to the moment we make juice out of it, when it starts losing it simply because it is dispersed in the liquid which is in contact with air.

That's what I know.

But somebody today told me otherwise, claiming that it's the plant that continuously supplies the orange with vitamin C.

This idea looks a bit silly to me, but I'm not a biologist, so I'm asking.

Incidentally, where in the orange is vitamin C contained? In each individual cell? I was once told that the oranges' cells (well, those that we like to eat and that actually make the juice) are those little drop-shaped things that are contained in the wedges (in a number that I'd say it's several hundreds?). Is that the case?

Comment: Isn't that what the covering is for?

Comment: @AsekuVena, I've also read that the peel itself contains more vitamin C then the rest

Comment: Maybe it is like the colony bacteria, who have their outer bits protect ️ the inner bacteria ?